# Where does firefox load page content

Tags: firefox

**Background**

I am reworking the remote-browser plugin for ettercap.
I catch the url and extract it.
I have set a filter with an "Accept: ..." Statement so not everything will be opened. But some Ads, Images still manage to pass this filter and open themselves in my browser.

I was hoping to find a solution in the firefox source code. I already looked over various files and researched a lot.

I need to know how firefox knows an incoming link via HTTP-Package is an image/ad for the page it is working on or it is a new page which must open in a new tab.

**Question**

So the question is:
In which file or method does firefox load external content like ads or images.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if this can be answered here as well, but you might try asking in the MozillaZine Extensions Development forum http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=19

Comment: I bet they say it is completely offtopic but I´ll give it a try. thx